# KeyboardAvoidingView react native bug with TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"position"} style={{width: "100%", position: "absolute", bottom: 0}} >
    <View style={styles.container} >
            <TextInput />
    </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

In this code snippet, if I add some text on TextInput and tap in the middle, the caret does not move.

If I remove KeryboardAvoidingView the caret moves and text is selected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, KeyboardAvoidingView is not always easy to handle. Here are a few ideas:

1. Try to use KeyboardAvoidingView without absolute positioning. If needed, wrap such view in another that uses `position: absolute`, but leave this one with relative positioning.
2. Try replacing `behaviour={"position"}` with `padding` or `height` [(Docs)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#behavior), and see what works best for your scenario. I usually use `padding` for Android and `position` for iOS.
3. Check if `KeyboardAvoidingView` has been imported from the correct module.
4. Edit your question to include the `styles.container` styling so we can see weather it has any impact on the implementation